# How to set the text position in ITextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I have drawn my own field with Itextsharp and I want to add text to this field. This code is line.

I write some text, but I cannot write to the field I want. I have to write on the line. So I have to add the title to the top of the page. I tried to adjust the position, but I couldn't.

How do I adjust the text position?

Comment: Have you considered to do it the other way around, e.g. drawing the text and underlining it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried spacing?

```
p.SpacingAfter = 30;
```

or

```
p.SpacingBefore = 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the iTextSharp has two ways of writing text.
One of them is the ContentByte, I think this is what you need.
I like to declare a global variable that stores the current position of contentByte. From it you can write the next element.
In this case you need to write the text at the top and then draw the shape from the final position of the text.

Comment: In this project you will find a number of methods using this technique, including doing just what you want.

https://github.com/jersonb/PdfGenerator/tree/Test

Comment: Probably you should simply post the method *doing just what the op wants.*